# Is html source code could be a selector in YUI like jQuery? Finding title and meta description by YUI

Tags: jquery, yui

I am new in YUI3 and trying some stuff similar to jquery, I am a jQuery guy and don't know to
how to achieve the same in YUI, which i am doing below in jQuery,

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" >
</script>
 <script language="javascript">
$(function(){
    var data = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>'+
               '<title>This is title</title> <meta name="description" content="This is description" /> </head><body></body></html>';
    var title=(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/m).exec(data)[1];
    console.log(title); //output: This is title
    var dom_list = $(data).find("meta").prevObject;
    $.each(dom_list, function(i,v){
        var c = $(v).attr('content');
        var n = $(v).attr('name');
        if(n!=undefined){
            if(n.toLowerCase()=='description'){
                desc = c;
            }
        }
    }); 
    console.log(desc); // output : This is description
});
</script>
```

Question: As data variable is the html source code and it is a selector in jquery and i
           can find meta tag in this, So, can i have the same in YUI?

Any suggestion would be appreciable.

Comment: I highly recommend http://www.jsrosettastone.com/ as a tool for highlighting the differences between jQuery and YUI. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>' + '<title>This is title</title> <meta name="description" content="This is description" /> </head><body></body></html>';
var title = (/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/m).exec(data)[1];
console.log(title); //output: This is title

var metaList = Y.Node.create(data).all("meta");
metaList.each(function(node) {
    var c = node.get('content'),
        n = node.get('name');
    if (n !== null) {
        if (n.toLowerCase() === 'description') {
            desc = c;
        }
    }
});
console.log(desc); // output : This is description
```

Can view a runnable example here: http://jsfiddle.net/brianjmiller/LTKs6/

You may also be interested in http://jsrosettastone.com which shows common translations between YUI and jQuery.

Comment: The solution you gave me is really very helpful and i was looking for this from 4 days. Thanks you very much for your time and efforts...